# Docker Registry behind TLS enabled reverse proxy (Traefik) - Remote Error: Bad Certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, reverse-proxy, docker-registry, traefik

So I am doing everything Dockerized here. Traefik is running in a container, as is my docker Registry instance. I am able to push/pull just fine from the registry if I hit it at `mydomain.com:5000/myimage`.

The problem comes when I try to hit it through 443 using `mydomain.com/myimage`. The setup I have here is Traefik reverse proxy listening on 443 at `mydomain.com`, and forwarding that request internally to `:5000` of my Registry instance.

When I go to push/pull from the Traefik url, it hangs and counts down waiting to retry on a loop. When I look at the logs of Registry, each I can see the instance IS in fact in communication with the reverse proxy Traefik, however, I get this error in the log over and over (on each push retry from the client side):

`2018/05/31 21:10:43 http: TLS handshake error from proxy_container_ip:port: remote error: tls: bad certificate`

Docker Registry is really tight and strict when it comes to the TLS issue. I'm using all self signed certs here, as I'm still in development. **Any idea what is causing this error?** I'm assuming that either the Traefik proxy detects that the certificate offered from Registry is not to be trusted (self-signed), and therefore does not complete the "push" request, or the other way around - Registry, when sending the response back through to the Traefik proxy detects that it is not to be trusted.

I can provide additional information if needed. Current setup is that both Traefik and Registry have their own set of .crt and .key files. Both (of course) TLS enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: What setup are you using? Is this Docker Swarm setup working https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381036/1065654 if you use your self signed certificate?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working solution with a self-signed certificate that you can try out on https://labs.play-with-docker.com

#### Server

Add a new instance `node1` in your Docker playground. We configure it as our server. Create a directory for the certificates:

```
mkdir /root/certs
```

Create wildcard certificate `*.domain.local`:

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /root/certs/domain.local.key -x509 -days 365 -out /root/certs/domain.local.crt
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...........+++
...........+++
writing new private key to '/root/certs/domain.local.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) []:
State or Province Name (full name) []:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) []:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []:*.domain.local
Email Address []:
```

Create two files **docker-compose.yml** and **traefik.toml** in directory `/root`. You can download them using:

```
wget https://gist.github.com/maiermic/cc9c9aab939f7ea791cff3d974725e4a/raw/8c5d787998d33c752f2ab369a9393905780d551c/docker-compose.yml
wget https://gist.github.com/maiermic/cc9c9aab939f7ea791cff3d974725e4a/raw/8c5d787998d33c752f2ab369a9393905780d551c/traefik.toml
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  frontproxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.swarmmode
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/ssl:ro
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.port=8080
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.domain.local
  docker-registry:
    image: registry:2
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.port=5000 # default port exposed by the registry
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:registry.domain.local
        - traefik.frontend.auth.basic=user:$$apr1$$9Cv/OMGj$$ZomWQzuQbL.3TRCS81A1g/ # user:password, see https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers
```

**traefik.toml**

```yml
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and use certificate, see https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/ssl/domain.local.crt"
      keyFile = "/etc/ssl/domain.local.key"

# Docker Swarm Mode Provider, see https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#docker-swarm-mode
[docker]
endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
swarmMode = true
```

Initialize Docker Swarm (replace `<ip-of-node1>` with the IP address of `node1`, for example `192.168.0.13`):

```yml
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <ip-of-node1>
```

Deploy traefik and Docker registry:

```yml
docker stack deploy myregistry -c ~/docker-compose.yml
```

#### Client

Since we don't have a DNS server, we change `/etc/hosts` (replace `<ip-of-node1>` with the IP address of our **server** `node1`, for example `192.168.0.13`):

```yml
echo "<ip-of-node1>   registry.domain.local traefik.domain.local" >> /etc/hosts
```

You should be able now to request the health status from traefik

```json
$ curl -ksS https://traefik.domain.local/health | jq .
{
  "pid": 1,
  "uptime": "1m37.501499911s",
  "uptime_sec": 97.501499911,
  "time": "2018-07-19 07:30:35.137546789 +0000 UTC m=+97.600568916",
  "unixtime": 1531985435,
  "status_code_count": {},
  "total_status_code_count": {},
  "count": 0,
  "total_count": 0,
  "total_response_time": "0s",
  "total_response_time_sec": 0,
  "average_response_time": "0s",
  "average_response_time_sec": 0
}
```

and you should be able to request all images (none) from our registry

```json
$ curl -ksS -u user:password https://registry.domain.local/v2/_catalog | jq .
{
  "repositories": []
}
```

Let's configure `docker` on our client. Create the directory for the registry certificates:

```json
mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.domain.local/
```

Get the certificate from our server:

```json
scp root@registry.domain.local:/root/certs/domain.local.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.domain.local/ca.crt # Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Now you should be able to login to our registry and add an image:

```json
docker login -u user -p password https://registry.domain.local
docker pull hello-world:latest
docker tag hello-world:latest registry.domain.local/hello-world:latest
docker push registry.domain.local/hello-world:latest
```

If you request all images from our registry after that, you should see

```json
$ curl -ksS -u user:password https://registry.domain.local/v2/_catalog | jq .
{
  "repositories": [
    "hello-world"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @TyRyDurden I've tested the complete @maiermic procedure at https://labs.play-with-docker.com/ (fantastic!) with excelent results (thx!!!) Probably your error with the certificate is because the step where you copy the certificate to the `/etc/docker/certs.d/YOUR_DOMAIN/ca.crt`. Note it has to be named that way "ca.crt" under your domain folder in `/etc/docker/certs.d` in the client host from where you want to access the registry.